# Method Overloading Versus Optional Parameters

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, methods, optional-parameters

I seem to recall reading there was an important difference between method overloading (and constructor chaining) and optional parameters in C# 4.0, but I haven't been able to locate anything acknowledging any difference.

Are there any important differences between the following two implementations?

First

```
public void Foo()
{
   Foo(String.Empty);
}

public void Foo(string message)
{
   Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Second

```
public void Foo(string message = "")
{
   Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with C#, but generally method overloading is used when you want to have parameters of a different type.  With optional parameters, they can only ever be that particular type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would favour method overloading. There are [known versioning](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/08/10/versioning-issues-with-optional-arguments.aspx) issues with optional parameters.

There is a very good article by **Jon Skeet** [here](http://codebetter.com/2011/01/11/c-in-depth-optional-parameters-and-named-arguments-2/).

Motivation for adding this was **making it easier to talk to COM** where methods can have many many parameters and less fora new design practice for C# classes

Comment: The “known versioning issues” aren’t actually a problem, nor an argument against using optional arguments. They only become a problem when a method is *modified* in the next version. But this can be solved easily by adding an overload instead of an optional parameter. Problem solved (and yes, Phil says something else but he made a mistake because he made the new argument optional).

Comment: The link to the Jon Skeet article is currently broken. Can't edit this answer right now, so here's an [archived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190901215524/http://codebetter.com/2011/01/11/c-in-depth-optional-parameters-and-named-arguments-2/)

Answer (score 3):

Optional parameters act like constants, and are replaced at compile-time.

```
public void Foo(string s = "default")
Foo();
```

Will generate the code for the caller:

```
public void Foo(string s)
Foo("default");
```

This means all the assemblies referencing yours will have the OLD default if you choose to change the default in a new version!

Overloads don't act like constants, and hide the defaults in your assembly.  This gives a clean upgrade path.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the second option. You could change the default string to some constant, and then at a later date you can change the value of the constant, such as :

```
constant String defaultString = String.Empty; //change this later if the default value needs to be something else, can't remember if the syntax is valid C# ;)
//...
public void Foo(string message = defaultString)
{
   Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Also, you have one less (albeit simple) function to maintain.

Comment: I don't recall anything talking about any major differences in functionality between method overloading and optional parameters- so I would default to optional parameters for code maintenance sake- and only use overloads if some circumstance required me to do so.

Comment: “`k_dflt_str`” – what?! No. No no no no.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: heh brain is currently in our PL/SQL standards mode. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Optional parameters is syntactic sugar.

Other than backwards compatibility with previous versions of .NET they are the same.

Comment: Their IL is different. Making me think that they're still different after the JIT. The backwards compatibility is also questionable. Since optional parameters were supported in IL earlier than .Net 4.